# Different logins in different tabs using Google Chrome?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, google-chrome, debugging, authorization

I need to observe real-time, back-and-forth I/O exchange between one (or more) guest(s) and one (ore more) admin(s).

Using Visual Studio and Google Chrome, is it possible to simultaneously run threads of the same web app under different roles? In other words, do multiple tabs / windows always share the same session for a given URL? Can a user use different logins in different tabs?

As a workaround, I am using an incognito window (separate session) but this limits me to two sessions only.

Comment: In Visual Studio are you attaching to the browser or to some web server or something (eg IIS). If you're attaching to IIS, then you could additionally run Internet Explorer (and IE in private). Of course this only gives you 2 more instances...

Comment: @Jonathan - yes good point, I am attaching to IIS Express (Google Chrome). In the past, I have run IE, Edge, and Firefox to allow concurrent sessions and even use different devices. I guess I will continue this way, I was just hoping I could display all on the same monitors instead of juggling!

Comment: You could also check out the SessionBox Chrome extension. It should allow you to run multiple sessions in the same Chrome instance across tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by others, various browser plugins exist, some of which require additional credentials. However, there is no out-the-box option available for Chrome as of this date. This feature will probably be offered one day.

For my purposes and with privacy in mind, the best alternative is to run IE, Chrome, Firefox concurrently, and launch anonymous tabs to double the number of sessions available.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has a feature with which you can create multiple "Chrome users". Each Chrome user gets its own isolated Chrome process. https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9025411

You can run your web app in two separate Chrome users and then easily differentiate in authentication.

Answer (score -1):

Ghost Browser lets you do this too and was built for this reason. (disc.: I'm the founder). Not exactly Chrome, but built on Chromium so it's the same experience. Additionally you can save your logged in States to pull certain ones up anytime so you can monitor multiple communication chains easily.